# Finding Occurance of Max Value in Array

Tags: c#, linq, max, find-occurrences

I am trying to find the Occurrences of a Maximum value in Integer Array.

e.g.

```
int[] ar = [3, 1, 2, 3];
```

Here, the Max `3` is repeated twice and so the expected output is `2`.

This works, I am getting count as `2` as the max value `3` occurred twice in the array

```
var max = int.MinValue;
var occurrenceCount = 0;

foreach(var x in ar)
{
    if (x >= max) max = x;
}

foreach(var x in ar)
{
    if (x == max) occurrenceCount++;
}
```

> Output: 2 //occurrenceCount

With `Linq` it's more simple,

```
var occurrenceCount = ar.Count(x => x == ar.Max())
```

> Output: 2 //occurrenceCount

Now without `Linq`, Is there any simplified or efficient way to do this?

Comment: you want to know how to max and count with more efficiency?

Comment: Yes, Want to know max and that max occurrences in the array

Comment: Which do you want: Simplified or efficient? There is always a trade-off. If you make a solution that only goes through the list once, it will be more efficient, but probably more complex.

Comment: [Max and GetCount](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,121902bcb741dfe1) reference here. There is a foreach in both maybe you can refactor them in a smart way.

Comment: @PalleDue, Nice query, I prefer efficient way then. Is that the linq query in the quesiton is not efficient?

Comment: @auburg, Not a performance but still wondering to know the other possible ways off Linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least, you can merge the two first arrays. I would still use the Linq solution. It is clearer. If you really want to talk about performance read [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) first.

So here is a O(n) solution:

```cs
int[] ar = {3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4};
int max = ar[0];
var occurrenceCount = 1;

for(var i = 1; i < ar.Length; i++)
{
    if (ar[i] > max) {
	max = ar[i];
	occurrenceCount = 1;
    }
    else if (ar[i] == max) {
        occurrenceCount++;
    }
}

WriteLine(max);
WriteLine(occurrenceCount);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BC4JAEIXPza@Yo7IWmd227dLVewfxIMtaA7XCqhGIv32blQyRhmGHx77vPd1udUvek@2KEiuHCocswTTBQ4LZtEfeUQI78Fm92VC5Yl9KeLG70bp3zlhtLk3PBoWpBKgbF4VfmjSfEzO73Nhbd2cpRAwDIA/VGHEalXgO2TEOsPl1EHds/hYEdJxe82jNIkWpOQa/s@KFmOkR4OqoMzlZEwVILvSKiqX3Hw)

- Note that you should handle the case where you array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I did not use the linq. I used lamda :)

```
 int[] ar = new[] { 3, 1, 2, 3 };


        var result = ar.GroupBy(x => x) //values groups
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Number = x.Key,
            Count = x.Count()
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count) //Short
        .FirstOrDefault(); //First Result


 result.Count // how many 

 result.Key   // max number
```

No Linq and No Lamda

```
 int[] ar = new[] { 3, 1, 2, 3 };
            Array.Sort(ar);
            Array.Reverse(ar);
            var maxValue = ar[0];
            var occurrenceCount = 0;
            foreach (var item in ar)
            {
                if (item == maxValue)
                    occurrenceCount++;
            }
```

Comment: It is still Linq... in fact, it wont works without `System.Linq`. It should be a hint ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on both [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,cb26c46274356e0d) of Max and GetCount on Enumerable you can simply factorise by adding one test in the foreach of the Max like :

```
public static int CountMax(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    int value = 0;
    bool hasValue = false;
    int count = 0;

    foreach (int x in source)
    {
        if (hasValue)
        {
            if (x > value)
            {
                value = x;
                count = 1;
            }
            else if (x == value)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            value = x;
            count = 1;
            hasValue = true;
        }
    }
    if (hasValue)
    {
        return count;
    }

    throw new Exception("no elements");
}
```

The cool part is that it's easy to make it more generik like :

```
public static int CountMax<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) where TSource : IComparable
```

Comment: Same logic than mine but slower. You can skip the first element. See my answer.

Comment: @aloisdg, yep same logic but with some fail safe and handeling enumerable, work on object that implement IComparable. From the System.LinQ implementation. It took just a bit more time to write and test with int and custom object

Comment: OP knows that it will use an array. At least switch to IReadOnlyList or IList. For the safety, yes OP should handle empty arrays.

Comment: @aloisdg, they both implement IEnumerable. So up to the one using the extention method to pass the type he want. For performance they should be the "same", it won't be noticable (tested: tenth of a nano secound on 10^6 element). I'm not trying to tell one is better than the other. From my side, I had fun looking for source and reading them a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try more flexible approach:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp42
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1 };
            //var array = new string[] { "a", "b", "a", "a" };

            var result = array.MaxCount ();
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static (long count, T max) MaxCount<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
        {
            if (comparer is null) comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

            (long count, T max) result = (0, default (T));

            foreach (var element in source)
            {
                if (result.count == 0) // is first element?
                {
                    result.max = element;
                    result.count = 1;

                    continue;
                }

                int compareResult = comparer.Compare (element, result.max);

                if (compareResult == 0) // element == max
                {
                    result.count++;
                }
                else if (compareResult > 0) // element > max
                {
                    result.max = element;
                    result.count = 1;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int[] list = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9 };
        Dictionary<int, int> occ = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            var val = list[i];
            var count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < list.Length; j++)
            {
                if (val == list[j])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            occ.TryAdd(val, count);
        }
        var maxCount = occ.Values.Max();
        var repNumber = occ.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == maxCount).Key;
```